# Convert Hex to (RFID) tag ID

Tags: python, hex, protocols, pyserial, rfid

I have purchased simple active RFID Reader which is connected through RS232 Serial Port to my Raspberry Pi 3 using [RS232 Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/12827). I want to read the tag id using the reader. I wrote a piece of code which meant to read the data from serial device. When I run it it is just waiting for something, (no error message). How do I read the tags using this reader with python code or shell script?

```
import serial                           

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyAMA0")    
ser.baudrate = 9600                     
data = ser.read(8)                       
print (data)
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to read the tag using:

```
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0")
```

as the `ttyAMA0` is Bluetooth in Raspberry Pi 3 (this only works on python 3.4. when I try python 2.7 the string is blank). My problem is that I have one tag and the ID of it is 02160323 but when I run this code the output is: `b'\xec`, `b'\xfe`, `b\xf6`, `b\xfc` and similar (not sure what those values are). How do I recognise the actual id?

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to convert the text into HEX and then convert it to numeric values.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("dev/ttyS0", 9600)
data = ser.read()
hexo = data.encode('hex')
i = ord(data)

print(i)
print(hexo)
```

The full ID is 8 integers long, and given output has not much to do with the ID on the card. How do I convert it to display 02160323?

**UPDATE 3**

My baundrate was wrong all this time, it should be `115200`. Now I receive value:
4000021603237440 and as clearly visible I have ID within it. Now I have to retrieve the data writing appropriate algorithm. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: The data on the RFID tag is more likely to be BCD or ASCII than binary, and typically includes parity or check bits or word(s) (e.g. BCD plus parity for 5-bit digits).  There could also be start and stop sentinals.  Instead of guessing, you should obtain the actual data format that is used by the tag(s) that you are trying to read.  IOW I'm not convinced that you're actually reading the correct data from the reader through the serial port. Just because you're getting *something* does not make it the actual data.

Comment: @sawdust you are right this was incorrect data. I was initially happy because I had communication and though it is the right data but I was wrong, now I can see the ID within the received data it is just matter of writing an algorithm to just leave 02160323 from this number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using 7 bytes not 8 and then the hexadecimal value will be immutable each time you run it. If you just want to validate for your ID then ignore first 4 string characters and pick the remaining 8. (Python 2.x)

```
import serial

while True:
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 115200)
    data = ser.read(7)
    hexo = str(data.encode('hex'))
    tagID = hexo[4:]
    tagID = tagID[:8]
    print(tagID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your update number 3. I recently had to do something similar for an RFID reader and the whole package had a bunch of different information (number of tags within the reader's range, number of anthenas that could reach a specific tag, information related to the status, the IDD and so on and so forth.

However, each scanner got a different sequence. The first step would be to identify that sequence within the documentation. Once you know that, I strongly suggest that you use the hexlify library to get an hexadecimal representation of your return signal. Working with the decimal system for byte reading and configuration is really not convenient.

To give you an example of what my reader sends when he read a tag:

Byte 1: STX
Byte 2: MSB length
Byte 3: LSB length
Byte 4: COM-ADR
Byte 5: 0xB0 (a constant to help you lock on to stuff)
Byte 6 to n-2: requested data
Byte n-1 to n: the CRC check value

The interesting content for you is located in the Byte 6 to n-2 range (I'm not saying that your scanner return something like that, but it gives you an idea). Also, RFID IDD are always best represented in hex value!